# Asp.net Generating Pages from DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

It is possible to generate permanent pages with asp.net with stuff stored on database?
For example a few locations/types and i want to do something like the single example:

**Location:** New York 
**Type:** Car

Generated Permanent Page With information:

**Cars in New York**

Generated link:
**mywebsite.com/cars/newyork**

At the moment i've done a search filter displays the results based on Selected Location and Selected type.

Hope you can give me some tips about this.

Comment: What do you mean by "permanent pages"?

Comment: Why not to have one view and pass that "generated" data from database to that view?

Comment: I think you want something like angular approach ? You can this something safely and really effective by angular or a framework similar.

Comment: @SeM maybe is the right way to do but the problem its i have a few dozens of Locations and a few dozens of Types. Anyway thank you all for the answers i will have a deep search on that.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to save HTML template in db and then use string.Format to insert values

e.g like that

```
string name = "test";
int age = 167;
string test = "{0} format {1}";

string[] args = new string[] { name, age.ToString() };

Console.WriteLine(string.Format(test, args));
```

prints: `test format 167`

Then you return View with string that is your html with inserted values and then you "display" (allow browser to render) it using

```
@model string

@Html.Raw(@Model)
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper.raw?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2

**But be careful, because it may be very dangerous if user is able to provide/manipulate those values. Read about XSS attack.**